# I have a table that holds date and the corresponding values. I want to write a sql query in a way it fills up the missing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, datetime

I have a table that holds date and their corresponding values. I want to write a query to fill in the missing dates and fill the values column with the value of the previous date.

```
DATE_         CURR            VALUE
2020-12-31    Dollar USA      73,8757
2020-12-30    Dollar USA      73,6567
2020-12-29    Dollar USA      73,7175
2020-12-26    Dollar USA      73,6921
2020-12-25    Dollar USA      74,8392
2020-12-24    Dollar USA      75,4571
```

OUTPUT:

```
DATE_         CURR            VALUE
2020-12-31    Dollar USA      73,8757
2020-12-30    Dollar USA      73,6567
2020-12-29    Dollar USA      73,7175
2020-12-28    Dollar USA      73,7175
2020-12-27    Dollar USA      73,7175
2020-12-26    Dollar USA      73,6921
2020-12-25    Dollar USA      74,8392
2020-12-24    Dollar USA      75,4571
```

```
with d as (
   select 
      min(DATE_) mi, 
      max(DATE_) mx, 
      max(DATE_) - min(DATE_) num 
   from CURR_TRAN), 
d1 as (
   select 
      level-1 + mi DATE_ 
   from d CONNECT by level <= num+1) 

select 
   d1.DATE_,
   last_value(VALUE ignore nulls) over (order by d1.DATE_) VALUE 
from d1 
left outer join CURR_TRAN on (d1.DATE_=CURR_TRAN.DATE_) 
order by d1.DATE_;
```

Comment: with d as (select min(DATE_) mi, max(DATE_) mx, max(DATE_) - min(DATE_) num from CURR_TRAN), 
d1 as (select level-1 + mi DATE_ from d 
CONNECT by level <= num+1)
select d1.DATE_,last_value(VALUE ignore nulls) over (order by d1.DATE_) VALUE 
from d1 left outer join CURR_TRAN on (d1.DATE_=CURR_TRAN.DATE_) order by d1.DATE_;

Comment: copied code to question because it does not belong in a comment

Comment: `CONNECT by` is new MySQL syntax for /me. I have never seen it... 

Comment: I have nt much idea on MYSQL, this is written using SQL SERVER

Comment: WHY did you put a tag `mysql` below your question ?

Comment: But [CONNECT BY](https://www.oradev.com/connect_by.jsp) seems to be Oracle syntax, so what kind of DBMS are you really using ?

Comment: I will remove the `mysql` tag, and it's up to you to add the correct tag (for the correct database system. You can do that using [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Below solution if for MySQL (because that is/was the tag below the question at the time of writing this... )

I created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78e2b8d40265c72c507276b85a805eb8) which seems to produce the requested result

```
insert into table1
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 as (
   SELECT min(DATE_) as D FROM table1
   
   union all
   
   SELECT DATE_ADD(D,INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
   from cte1 
   WHERE D<(SELECT max(DATE_) from table1)
)
select D,CURR,VALUE
FROM (
   select 
      cte1.D,
      p.CURR,
      p.VALUE,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cte1.D ORDER BY p.DATE_ desc) R
   from cte1
   LEFT join table1 p on p.DATE_ < cte1.D
   LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.DATE_ = cte1.D
   WHERE table1.DATE_ IS NULL
   ORDER BY D) y
WHERE y.R=1;
```

Comment: I would take out the second table1 join.  It's purpose is to remove matches to the original table, but the OP shows they want them in their desired results.

Comment: I only want/need matches that do not exits, because I am inserting them (first line of script)   In the final `table1` all dates between the first and last existing date will be there.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server try something like this:

```
DECLARE @minDate DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(DATE_) FROM table1)
DECLARE @maxDate DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(DATE_) FROM table1)
DECLARE @currentDate DATETIME = @minDate

WHILE @currentDate < @maxDate
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Date_ = @currentDate)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT TOP(1) @currentDate, CURR, VALUE
    FROM table1
    WHERE DATE_ < @currentDate
    ORDER BY Date_ DESC
  END
  
  SET @currentDate = @currentDate + 1
END
```

If you have multiple currencies in this table than you need to change the `IF NOT EXISTS ...` and the WHERE clause in the INSERT statement